Adding column without horizontal lines in a table built using booktabs
Consider the following table
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ccc} \toprule
A & B & C \\ \midrule
D & E & F \\ \midrule
G & H & I \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

I would like to add a column of values (1, 2, 3) to the left of the table that does not contain the horizontal lines created by \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule. What is the best way to do this?

use cmidrule and specify columns 3-4

@DavidCarlisle I am aware of cmidrule, but what about toprule and bottomrule? ctoprule is not a defined command.

you can use cmidrule and the optional arguments to make a thicker rule or use full width top and bottom, which might look better anyway

As @David Carlisle said, you can use \cmidrule.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lccc} \cmidrule[1pt]{2-4}
1 & A & B & C \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
2 & D & E & F \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
3 & G & H & I \\ \cmidrule[.8pt]{2-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}


